# DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

```dart
final dio = Dio();
    try {
      await dio.request(
        'https://api.example.com/api/v1/auth/validateMobile',
        data: {"phoneNo": "+91999999999"},
        options: Options(
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
                'Bearer $token',
            'content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        ),
      );
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

```
I/flutter (16336): DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [401]
I/flutter (16336): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
I/flutter (16336): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
I/flutter (16336): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (16336): #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
I/flutter (16336): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I'm getting 401 error even though I'm passing authorization header with correct token. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Mate, your question literally become answer for my problem lol! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Use this parameter along with other option parameters, it worked for me, I hope it works for you too

> dio.request( ***, options: Options(...

```
Options (validateStatus: (_) => true)
```

If it does not work, you can try this

```
Options (
 validateStatus: (_) => true,
 contentType: Headers.jsonContentType,
 responseType:ResponseType.json,
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: how to attach it to dio ?  @Sh4msi

Comment: dio.request(
       ***,
        options: Options(...

Answer (score 1):

you should pass content-type like this:

```
HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
```

here is an example of using this instead of Dio:

```
fetchSearchedNews(String searchParameter) async {
    final queryParameters = {
      'keywords': searchParameter,
    };
    final uri = Uri.https('$baseUrl', '/v1/search', queryParameters);
    final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
          'YOUR KEY HERE',
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body);
      return NewsModel.fromJson(items).news;
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      throw Exception('Error 401');
    } else if (response.statusCode == 429) {
      throw Exception('Error 429');
    } else {
      throw Exception('null');
    }
  }
```

Comment: tried still not working

Comment: use this instead of Dio to see if it works, I edited my answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, surround your request with a try catch of dio as follows

```
try{
  //put your dio request here....
} on DioError catch(e){
  // in case of a code that is not success, you can get it here through object 'e'
}
```

THANK ME LATER!

Answer (score 0):

#### Check whether you may forgot to pass some parameters in header.

Today I faced the same issue and I forgot to pass the two parameters in header.

I've tried with [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72460609/1318946) answer but after that I realise that I've to pass the params in header and now its working successfully.